# Error: "Version code not found in manifest."

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build the signed app bundle, so publishing. All I did was update the OS versions and some graphics. The app runs on the ADKs just fine.
When building the signed apk, I get this error message:

> "Version code not found in manifest."

This is the error log:

> "Caused by: com.android.ide.common.workers.WorkerExecutorException:
>   1 exception was raised by workers:
>   com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.manifest.ManifestVersionException$VersionCodeMissingException:
>   Version code not found in manifest."

Thanks for anyone that can help me sort this small issue out. I searched on here and could not find a good fix.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sevillasoundservices.warningshot">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShotgunSensing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_shotgun"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RifleSensing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rifle"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PistolSensing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pistol"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

The Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sevillasoundservices.warningshot"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName '1.0.2'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-    android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

---

I am hoping someone here can tell me what is missing. I expect to simply insert some code on the manifest file to sort this out, however, all other examples of other coders manifests do not have any version showing anywhere.

Comment: Can you add your module's gradle file as well?

Comment: Yes, check the question again, it should appear there now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `versionCode` to your gradle. Something like below...

```
   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sevillasoundservices.warningshot"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionName '1.0.2'
        versionCode 3
    }
```

The `versionCode` is an incremental integer that is used to determine which version is higher than the other. I think this is only enforced on signed APKs, that's why you haven't seen the error earlier.

More info can be found in [Android Developer Guides](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, and report back.

Comment: That worked! Now to remember how to upload, and what gets uploaded LOL. I took a long long break from this, too long.

Comment: It'd be good if you accept the answer to let everyone know what the solution to your problem was. That's what SO is all about

Answer (score 3):

You need to add versionCode code as follows.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 4
        versionName '0.0.4.'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

For me, Error was in my build.gradle that I was trying to generate VersionCode **dynamically**. For that I need to add a method that generated versionCode. It had no issue till I tried to generate a release.  But got the error when I tried creating signed bundle.

```
def getVersionCode() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd')
    return formattedDate
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode getVersionCode()
        versionName '0.0.4.'
        
    }
```

The reason was my method name getVersionCode() conflicted with the default getter for field versionCode and was hiding it.

> **If you want dynamic generation like the above your method name has to be something other than getVersionCode(), may be generatetVersionCode()**

Comment: Same thing's happening on my end. Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: @GeneM my answer was old. After posting here, I had found the root cause of the issue. Now editted.

Comment: Got it all figured out yesterday as well. But thanks for getting back! +1

Answer (score 0):

**versionCode can't be 0.**

When i build aab i get the seam problem.But it's ok to build apk. I'm so confusion.

I try to so many way to fix this.

I use gradle-7.5-bin to build my project. I downgrade gradle 7.5 to 7.4.1 or 7.3.1 but it dosen't work for me. When build other app. It's build sucess, so i compare the infomation.

My project information.

```
AppBuildFail{
        ......
        versionName "1.0.0.0"
        versionCode 0

        applicationId "my.project.id"
        ......
    }
```

The buils sucess project.

```
AppBuildSucess{
        ......
        versionName "1.0.0.0"
        versionCode 2
        applicationId "the app id"
        ......
    }
```

So i change the versionCode of the AppBuildFail to 1. then it's work for me.